# django template counter with "with" statement

Tags: django, django-templates

```
{% with counter=1 %}
    {% for order in sales %}
        <tr>
            {% ifchanged order.date and order.dealer %}
                <td scope="row">{{ counter }}</td>
                {% with counter=counter|add:1 %}
                {% endwith %}
            {% else %}
                <td></td>
            {% endifchanged %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

why is the counter '1' all the time? How can the counter be increased by 1 each time it is inside ifchanged statement?

Comment: `with` does not work that way: it is a locally scoped variable, nor should you try to do such logic in the template. Such logic belongs in the view.

Comment: Can you explain *what* you aim to achieve?

Comment: I just wanted to show S.No like 1, 2, 3.... but only when date differs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`{% with … %}`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#with) does *not* work as variable assignment, it creates a *locally scoped* variable. Chat bots like *ChatGPT* seems to "think"<sup>†</sup> that this is equivalent to assignment, but it is not.

So in this case, between the *inner* `{% with … %}` tags, there will be a *different* `count` variable that is two, and the outer one remains one.

But this is not what templates are for. Django's template language is deliberately a bit restrictive, to prevent people writing logic like you did. This logic belongs in a view where you "prepare" data to be rendered effectively. This will separate concerns better, and Django's template language is also not very efficient, so it would only slow down the rendering significantly.

---

<sup>†</sup> of course as far as a chatbot can *think*, since it is essentially a probabilistic model.